# Change a value in a XML document with SimpleXML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a XML file which I want to replace a value with a constant when it is empty, checking an attribute (annotation_ref). The XML tags are something like this:

```
    <ANNOTATION>
        <REF_ANNOTATION ANNOTATION_ID="id" ANNOTATION_REF="1234">
            <ANNOTATION_VALUE></ANNOTATION_VALUE>
        </REF_ANNOTATION>
    </ANNOTATION>
```

So, the result of the transformation would be:

```
    <ANNOTATION>
        <REF_ANNOTATION ANNOTATION_ID="id" ANNOTATION_REF="1234">
            <ANNOTATION_VALUE>my_constant</ANNOTATION_VALUE>
        </REF_ANNOTATION>
    </ANNOTATION>
```

But instead of that, I get this:

```
    <ANNOTATION>
        <REF_ANNOTATION ANNOTATION_ID="id" ANNOTATION_REF="1234">
            <ANNOTATION_VALUE/>
        </REF_ANNOTATION>
    <ANNOTATION_VALUE>my_constant</ANNOTATION_VALUE></ANNOTATION>
```

My code is the next:

```
$document = simplexml_load_file("my_document.eaf");
$aux = $annotation_document->ANNOTATION;

foreach ($aux as $aux2) {
 if ($aux2->REF_ANNOTATION->attributes()->ANNOTATION_REF == $my_condition) {
   $aux2->ANNOTATION_VALUE = $my_constant;
 }
}
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking to the wrong node:

```
if ($aux2->REF_ANNOTATION->attributes()->ANNOTATION_REF == $my_condition) {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
 $aux2->ANNOTATION_VALUE = $my_constant;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You should have

```
$aux2->REF_ANNOTATION->ANNOTATION_VALUE = $my_constant;
```